# IOS Get an Array inside NS(Mutable)Dictionary

Tags: ios

I am trying to get an array inside a NSMutableDictionary that looks like this:

```
{
coments =     (
);
"foto_user" = "<null>";
fotos =     (
            {
        fecha = "2012-08-31 19:44:31";
        id = 4926;
        nombre = "image5773.jpg";
        posicion = 0;
        ruta = "img/";
        tipo = 1;
    },
            {
        fecha = "2012-08-31 19:44:31";
        id = 4927;
        nombre = "image1779.jpg";
        posicion = 0;
        ruta = "img/";
        tipo = 1;
    },
            {
        fecha = "2012-08-31 19:44:31";
        id = 4928;
        nombre = "image5938.jpg";
        posicion = 0;
        ruta = "img/";
        tipo = 1;
    },
            {
        fecha = "2012-08-31 19:44:32";
        id = 4929;
        nombre = "image4424.jpg";
        posicion = 0;
        ruta = "img/";
        tipo = 1;
    }
);
"have_coments" = 0;
id = 40505;
"id_lugar" = "<null>";
"id_pais" = 28;
"id_user" = "<null>";
iso = fr;
link = "<null>";
lugar = Paris;
"nombre_pais" = "France";
root = "http://www.domain.com/";
tags =     (
);
titulo = "Sunset";
"url_share" = "http://www.friktrip.com/experiencia/40505";
videos =     (
);
}
```

And I am using this code :

```
             //Get data from dictionary
             NSMutableArray *foto = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
             foto = [OnlineObjects objectAtIndex:1];
```

But the "fotoarray"  array stay empty trying to get the info from the NSMutableArray.

```
             //Get only the nombre Key of the NSMutableArray
             NSArray *fotoarray = [foto valueForKey:@"nombre"];
```

What is the way to make an Array with all objects with the key name "nombre" ?

Comment: 1) What you have posted is not a mutable array, is an `NSDictionary`. 2) What is `OnlineObjects` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have posted is the description of an `NSDictionary` (lets call it `myDict` from now on). The quickest way to get all `nombre` values from `fotos` array is this:

```
NSArray *nombres = [myDict valueForKeyPath:@"fotos.nombre"];
```

Comment: What if I want to copy multiple attributes from ArrayOfPropertyList into my ArrayOfPropertylist. e.g. fotos.nombre and fotos.position ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli I'm not sure if I get this correctly, but I guess you could grab the values into two separate arrays and merge them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks you got me. But could you tell me how to merge ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli Merging two arrays is as simple as `NSArray *combined = [arrayOne arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arrayTwo];`

Comment: Ooops but it just added not merged in sense of Dictionary :/

Comment: Please see this question I explained it clearly what i want
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992235/copy-from-array-of-dictionary-to-array-of-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment42515759_26992235