# Copy from array of dictionary to array of dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios8, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am collecting Ids in an array from an array of Dictionaries like this

```
NSArray *places=   @[ 
    {place_id = @"3dsfdDfGDH";      
    place_url = @"/Peru/Lambayeque/Chiclayo";      
    place_name = @"Peru";}
     ,
    {place_id = @"HUHiKcZVU7ItMyQ";       
    place_url = @"/Peru/La+Libertad/Huanchaco";      
    place_name = @"Peru";}
    ,
    {place_id = @"7JL1K5FVUbg0vg";        
    place_url = @"/United+Kingdom/England/Buckley+Hill";      
    place_name = @"United Kingdom";}
                   ];

NSArray *placeIds= [places valueForKeyPath:place_id];
```

It is working perfectly but What I want is another Array with place_id as well as place_url but NOT Name.
something Like

I want NSArray *PlaceIdAndURL to have dictionaries like below

```
                   @[
         {place_id = @"3dsfdDfGDH";     
        place_url = @"/Peru/Lambayeque/Chiclayo";}
         ,
        {place_id = @"HUHiKcZVU7ItMyQ";       
        place_url = @"/Peru/La+Libertad/Huanchaco";}
        ,
        {place_id = @"7JL1K5FVUbg0vg";        
        place_url = @"/United+Kingdom/England/Buckley+Hill";}
                       ];
```

How can I get without looping whole array just like the one i got first one with `ValueForKeyPath` above

Comment: Without iterating?  I doubt you can.  Why don't you want to iterate?

Comment: Just a note here that the posted code is _not_ valid ObjC code (despite that we might understand the structure, it also may be confusing for several users facing the same problem). I also doubt that it could be done with an one-liner, iteration/creation or some kind of a mapping function could do the work though.

Comment: Because I have many other keys this one i just created for simplification. And I am working with core data so If it's possible without Iteration then it's good otherwise i ll go with iteration.

Comment: also if I get two separate arrays with valueForKeyPath method, Can I merge them into one array with two keys like above in my Question.

Comment: i posted an answer with working code and may have another suggestion but I need to know if you want care if the original dictionaries are modified in the process or you want to create copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in one liner that won't iterate....but here is the code that will do the job. Actually, you can make this logic into a method and add as your category to NSArray and NSMutableArray...

places_dup will contain the dictionaries you are looking for.

```
NSArray *places=   @[
                     @{@"place_id" : @"NFxmX.VVU7LtQwQ",
                       @"place_url" : @"/Peru/Lambayeque/Chiclayo",
                       @"place_name" : @"dadfasdf"}
                     ,
                     @{@"place_id" : @"HUHiKcZVU7ItMyQ",
                       @"place_url" : @"/Peru/La+Libertad/Huanchaco",
                       @"place_name" : @"dadfasdf"}
                     ,
                     @{@"place_id" : @"7JL1K5FVUbg0vg",
                       @"place_url" : @"/United+Kingdom/England/Buckley+Hill",
                       @"place_name" : @"dadfasdf"}
                     ];
NSMutableArray *places_dup = [@[] mutableCopy];
[places enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) item;
    NSMutableDictionary *filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];
    [filteredDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"place_name"];
    [places_dup addObject:filteredDictionary];
}];
```

Comment: Will this block run on main Que ?

Comment: This will execute on the current thread, if it is main it is main.